# Failed to integrate downloaded changesets: Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch

Tags: mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am a newbie with MongoDB Realm. I am developing an android app that fetches a list of employees from the server and then displays it on the list. This is the schema I configured on Mongo atlas:

```
{
  "title": "Employee",
  "bsonType": "object",
  "required": [
    "_id",
    "_partition",
    "name",
    "employeeId",
    "company",
    "role",
    "isActive",
    "created"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "_partition": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "cardId": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "company": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "created": {
      "bsonType": "double"
    },
    "employeeId": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "featureVector0": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector1": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector10": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector11": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector12": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector13": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector14": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector15": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector16": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector17": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector18": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector19": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector2": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector3": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector4": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector5": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector6": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector7": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector8": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "featureVector9": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "double"
      }
    },
    "isActive": {
      "bsonType": "bool"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "password": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "role": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is object

```
open class Employee(
    @PrimaryKey var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId(),
    var _partition: String = "",
    @Required
    var cardId: String? = null,
    var company: String = "",
    var created: Double = 0.0,
    var employeeId: String = "",
    @Required
    var featureVector0: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector1: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector10: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector11: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector12: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector13: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector14: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector15: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector16: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector17: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector18: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector19: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector2: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector3: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector4: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector5: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector6: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector7: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector8: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    @Required
    var featureVector9: RealmList<Double> = RealmList(),
    var isActive: Boolean = false,
    var name: String = "",
    @Required
    var password: String? = null,
    var role: String = ""
): RealmObject() {}
```

I use below code for fetching data from Server.

```
employeeRealmConfig = SyncConfiguration.Builder(realmApp.currentUser(),"Employee").
            allowQueriesOnUiThread(true)
            .allowWritesOnUiThread(true).build()
        Realm.getInstanceAsync(employeeRealmConfig, object : Realm.Callback() {
            override fun onSuccess(realm: Realm) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Realm.getInstanceAsync onSuccess")
                //fetch full data for the first time
                employeeRealmUi = realm
                employeeAll = realm.where<Employee>().findAllAsync()
                Log.d(TAG,"employee sizes = ${employeeAll.size}")
                employeeAll.addChangeListener(employeeRealmChangeListener)

            }

            override fun onError(exception: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Realm.getInstanceAsync ${exception.message}")
            }
        })
private val employeeRealmChangeListener =
    OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Employee>> { _, changeSet ->
        Log.d(TAG,"employeeRealmChangeListener - new employeeAll size " + employeeAll.size.toString())
    }
```

After running the android app: I got the below issue:

```
2022-06-29 16:23:09.801 6394-6473/com.example.testrealmproject E/REALM_SYNC: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Failed to integrate downloaded changesets: Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Property 'cardId' in class 'Employee' is nullable on one side and not on the other.
2022-06-29 16:23:09.805 6394-6473/com.example.testrealmproject E/REALM_JAVA: Session Error[wss://realm.mongodb.com/]: CLIENT_BAD_CHANGESET(realm::sync::ClientError:112): Bad changeset (DOWNLOAD)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: It's important you perform troubleshooting before posting questions and include those results. Please add a breakpoint to your code and step through it line by line inspecting vars and code execution along the way. When you spot something that isn't as expected, include what line that it occurred on and what the expected result was in the question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

This problem is resolved by uninstall application.